# Count empty lines or line breaks in unix

Tags: unix, hive

I have a file which I am loading to Hive.It has 1 header record and 2 trailer records.I am skipping these 3 rows.

WC -l on the file gives 780112 records.780108 records are getting loaded to hive table.

Downloading this file to excel has 780113 records including header and trailer.
 I am assuming there is some empty line or line break in the file which could be those 2 missing lines and why does WC -l gives the wrong count.

How to find it ?

I have tried to search empty line using  :g in vi editor but did not give a match.

Comment: I found the issue was with skip trailer was not working properly.

Answer (score 0):

Work around to skip trailer in landing table by giving a filter condition